# Show colors in Git Bash Windows for behat

Tags: php, behat, git-bash, gherkin

I have a question. So I'm using the last version of behat and the Git Bash on windows 7. The Git Bash has the colors but when I run the scenario for behat the text have one color (black).
I tried :

```
bin/behat --ansi
```

But not result. Help me please.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to solve this issue too, but without any success. As far as I know windows simply does not support the "coloring" produced by Behat, it's only supported on Linux systems and MacOS. I am executing my tests via Ubuntu running in VirtualBox which works for me just fine.